# Adding data values to a stacked bar chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, bar-chart, stacked-bar-chart

i am doing a data science module at Uni, and am relatively new at R. I am having trouble with adding data values to my stacked chart, and have no clue on how to fix it.

My current code is this:

```
bp <- ggplot(race_death) +
   geom_bar(aes(x = Race, fill = Died)) +
   ggthemes::theme_economist()+ 
   scale_fill_manual(values = my_palette)+
   geom_label(aes(x = Race, y = n ,label = n), size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5, reverse = FALSE), Deaths) bp +
   coord_flip()
```

But the graph shows this:

[image]

The numbers are correct, but they are in the wrong places, e.g. 454 should be in the middle of the green bar, instead of in the orange. How do i go about fixing this?

Comment: Try with adding the `group` aes, i.e. do `geom_label(aes(x = Race, y = n ,label = n, group = Died)`. The `group`ing determines the order of the stack. For the bars you have set that implicitly via `fill=`.

Comment: @stefan wow, that was surprisingly simple, thanks so much!